# Django variable in template resulting in SQL query

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python / Django coming from a PHP background and had a question. I have the debug toolbar enabled and it appears as if when I reference variables in the template that I built in the view and pass to the template it is result in an SQL query. In other words, the template is making another query to the database instead of using the variable that was built in the view.

Here is one example of what I am talking about. With this being the case, a page that has many variables printed could have well over 100 queries which doesn't seem right. I am assuming that there is something fundamental that I am missing and have done some thorough research but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image: one example]

View:

```
def test(request):

    weather = []
    w = Weather_main.objects.filter(location_id=3)
    w = w.select_related('location__name')
    weather.append(w)

    w = Weather_main.objects.filter(location_id=6)
    w = w.select_related('location__name')
    weather.append(w)

    w = Weather_main.objects.filter(location_id=9)
    w = w.select_related('location__name')
    weather.append(w)

    context = {'weather': weather,
         'num_weather_locs': range(len(weather))}

    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

Template:

```
{% load app_filters %}

<BODY>

{{ status }} <br><br>

{% if weather %}
    {% for w in weather %}
        {{ w.0.location.name }}<br>
        {{ w.0.weather_date }}<br><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>Weather does not exist</p>
{% endif %}

</BODY>
```

Comment: what happen if you change `{{ w.0.location.name }}` to this `{{ w.location[0].name }}`

Comment: @Charlesiam this is django template.  That would not work

Answer (score 2):

In order to join weather info for different locations, better use a single query with [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
def test(request):
    weather = Weather_main.objects.filter(location_id__in=[3, 6, 9]).select_related('location__name')

    context = {'weather': weather}
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

Then, in the template, iterate over the `weather` queryset:

```
{% for w in weather %}
    {{ w.location.name }}<br>
    {{ w.weather_date }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```